# StopIteration error while using next() for Monocular depth estimation code

Tags: python, stopiteration

I am referencing https://keras.io/examples/vision/depth_estimation/#visualizing-samples code for one of my project however, I am getting error related to StopIteration. Could someone please suggest how this can be rectified?

```
def visualize_depth_map(samples, test=False, model=None):
    input, target = samples
    cmap = plt.cm.jet
    cmap.set_bad(color="black")

    if test:
        pred = model.predict(input)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 3, figsize=(50, 50))
        for i in range(6):
            ax[i, 0].imshow((input[i].squeeze()))
            ax[i, 1].imshow((target[i].squeeze()), cmap=cmap)
            ax[i, 2].imshow((pred[i].squeeze()), cmap=cmap)

    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 2, figsize=(50, 50))
        for i in range(6):
            ax[i, 0].imshow((input[i].squeeze()))
            ax[i, 1].imshow((target[i].squeeze()), cmap=cmap)


visualize_samples = next(
    iter(DataGenerator(data=df, batch_size=6, dim=(HEIGHT, WIDTH)))
)
visualize_depth_map(visualize_samples)
```

Traceback below:

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1f95b664ead3> in <module>()
     19 
     20 
---> 21 visualize_samples = next(iter(DataGenerator(data=df, batch_size=6, dim=(HEIGHT, WIDTH))))
     22 visualize_depth_map(visualize_samples)

StopIteration:
```

Comment: can you please paste your error traceback here? which can help us to look

Comment: @TamilSelvan added Traceback

Comment: What is the shape of your dataframe `df`?

Comment: I am referring the same dataset and code as given in https://keras.io/examples/vision/depth_estimation/

Comment: Can you print out `df.shape` just before you apply the `next`?

Comment: Output is `(0, 3)`

Comment: That means no rows, no data, and therefore an imidiate `StopIteration`. You need to make sure your `df` contains data.